# Не работает скрипт движения, если добавляю анимацию

Tags: unity3d

Не работает скрипт движения, если добавляю анимацию. Сама анимация бега проигрывается при нажатии клавиши движения, но сам персонаж отказывается бегать. При удалении всей анимации, скрипт движения и прыжка начинает работать. Или если я включу Apply Root Motion. Скрипт прыжка и движения начнет работать, но сама анимация проигрываться не будет.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Такое может быть если у Вас в анимации персонажа изменяется параметр `transform.position`, то есть в ходе анимации персонаж как-бы залипает в определённых координатах и думает, что так оно и нужно. Покажите, пожалуйста, окно animation, скрипт игрока и окно animator, тогда скорее всего, смогу объяснить, как исправить, потому что проблема может жить как в скрипте, так и в неправильно настроенной анимации.